# Linking my Azure App Service to my API repository & pipeline in Azure DevOps for deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I'm trying to link my App Service to a pipeline of my repository in Azure DevOps but whenever I click the `Get started` link, it directs me to a portal where it's trying to make a brand new organization instead of using my current organization. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? Perhaps I forgot to link some stuff together?

Comment: Log in to your Azure account in one tab of your browser by going to portal.azure.com then log in to DevOps account in another tab by visiting dev.azure.com > Start Free it will route you to your DevOps account if its connected to your Azure subscription account or same user. https://i.imgur.com/0NbgZVE.png https://i.imgur.com/jpYXXgn.png

Answer (score 1):

I logged into my Azure account in Portal with the same account as my Azure DevOps account, Refer below:-

[image]

And in the next tab I logged into my Azure DevOps account like below:-

**Click on Start Free**

[image]

***I got logged into Azure DevOps account as I have already logged into my Azure account with same credentials it did not ask me to Sign in Refer below:-***

[image]

[image]

To link your Azure tenant with Azure DevOps, Click on Switch Directory and then Switch to your Azure account directory like below:-

[image]

As By default the url is routed to Microsoft Account Directory like below:-

[image]

Now, You can link or run your Azure App Service with Azure DevOps in two ways, Import the Source code of your Web app in Azure Repos like below:-

[image]

Now, click on Pipeline > New Pipeline > Select your Web app source code repository > And then either create a new YAML pipeline from scratch or select existing YAML pipeline like below:-

[image]

Selected my Azure Web app like below

[image]

My web app in Portal:-

[image]

YAML pipeline to deploy Web app :-

[image]

Another way is via Release pipeline.

[image]

Reference [**MS Document**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/azure-devops-for-beginners-how-to-set-up-your-account/ba-p/3790002#:%7E:text=Scroll%20down%20and%20click%20on%20My%20Azure%20DeveOps,account.%20Step%203%20Click%20on%20Create%20new%20organization.)  to create AzureDevOps organization.